# Как написать архитектуру для тестов fastapi asyncpg?

Tags: юнит-тесты, fastapi, asyncpg

У меня есть небольшое апи, с двумя роутами. Бд на asyncpg. Я хочу написать для них тесты, но нахожу только репозитории с миллиардами тестов и функций, где запутаться легче, чем выпрыгнуть из окна. Подскажите пожалуйста, как организовать лучше conftest.py и тесты роутов, в папке tests?

Вот репозиторий: https://github.com/utsiye/api_parking_lots_ai